# Simplest Liouville Manifold not of Finite Type, or - Liouville Cobordism Structure on Pair of Pants?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I've been trying to produce the simplest possible example of a Liouville manifold which wouldn't be of finite type (a Liouville manifold is said to be of finite type if its skeleton is compact), and the answer is probably "an infinite number of pairs of pants glued to each other on the right, and the left-most circle filled in by a disk." That would produce a surface of infinite genus which would have infinite-dimensional homology, and therefore couldn't be of finite type.

However, what I've realized is that I'm unable to produce a Liouville cobordism structure on the pair of pants. Intuitively, it should absolutely exist, but my only two ideas have failed. I list them here in case they might be a partial solution:

- Take the pair of pants $P$ as a subset of the torus $\mathbb{T}^2= \{(e^{i\theta}, e^{i \varphi})\}$ - more precisely, the top half of the torus with a disk around the top removed. Then it inherits a symplectic form $\omega = d \theta \wedge d \varphi$ which is exact on $P$, because $\theta$ is well-defined, going to $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ for example, and thus we can pick $\lambda = \theta d \varphi$ as a primitive. The resulting Liouville vector field is $Z = \theta \partial_\theta$, which will have two critical points on the disk at the top if I center the disk around $\{\theta = 0\}$, or will simply fail to be outward-pointing if I place the disk elsewhere inside the half torus.
- I thought the gradient of the height function might work, but if I use a parametrization of the torus by $\theta$ and $\varphi$ such as, for example $$u(\theta, \varphi) = ((1+\frac{1}{2} \cos{\theta})\cos{\varphi}, \frac{1}{2} \sin{\theta}, (1+\frac{1}{2}\cos{\theta})\sin{\varphi}),$$and denote by $h$ the projection onto the $z$-axis, both the flat metric and the Euclidean metric give me something relatively complicated, and certainly not $\mathcal{L}_{\nabla h} \omega = \pm \omega$. (In the case of the Euclidean metric, I considered a symplectic form better suited to it: $\omega = -\frac{1}{4} (2 + \cos{\theta}) d \theta \wedge d \varphi$. This was so that the resulting complex structure would be an isometry)

Does there exist a Liouville cobordism structure on $P$ which one could explicitly describe, or would one have to use a perturbation argument? I would also be open to any other example of a non-finite-type Liouville manifold - I am aware of one on $\mathbb{R}^8$ constructed by McLean, but I'd like to see one without Floer theory.

Comment: Are Weinstein handles explicit enough? A subclass of Liouville manifolds are those that can be built out of Weinstein handles (Alan Weinstein "Contact surgery and symplectic handlebodies," Hokkaido Mathematical Journal, Hokkaido Math. J. 20(2), 241-251, (February 1991)); these are called Weinstein manifolds. Your description of gluing a bunch of pairs of pants together can just be though of as a 0-handle with a bunch of 1-handles attached.

Comment: Can one glue along parts which aren't the boundary? The only way that I can see a pair of pants being obtained from 1-handles (which, as far as I understand, are $S^1 \times D^1$ topologically) is taking two 1-handles, bending one so that it's half a torus, and gluing the "straight" one to the middle of the "bent" one.

Comment: Even smoothly, when an $n$-dimensional index $k$-handle attaches along a specified $(n-1)$-manifold $\Sigma$ along a framed $(k-1)$-sphere to produce an $n$-dimensional cobordism, you're really taking $\Sigma \times [0,1]$, and attaching the handle to the positive boundary of $\Sigma \times [0,1]$ (and smoothing corners). For $n=2$, $k=1$, and $\Sigma = S^1$, the attaching sphere is just two points, and it comes with one of two framing choices, one of which gives something orientable (like the handles of a tote bag), the other non-orientable. Since we're symplectic, we have the orientable one.

Comment: So I think you're first "bent" one is just the $S^1 \times [0,1]$ along which you're attaching (though I'm not certain I understand your description exactly).